# How can I display the alphanumeric ID on the front end of my Windows form and stop accepting more entries after a limit is reached?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a Student table in my SQL Server database which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] 
(
    [Id]   INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [MyId] AS 'S' + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Id), 2) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I have created a front-end page through which a user can add entries into this table.

[image]

When the user clicks on the `Create` button above, it takes him to the following window:

[image]

I want the `MyId` value to be displayed in the circled text-box instead of the `Id` value. In the case of the window above, I want S11 to be displayed instead of 11 but I do not know how to accomplish that without hard-coding the zeroes. The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
var query_1 = "SELECT TOP 1 Id + 1 " +
              "FROM dbo.Student mo " +
              "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Student mi " +
              "                 WHERE mi.Id = mo.Id + 1)" +
              "ORDER BY Id";

using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand sa = new SqlCommand(query_1, connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader da = sa.ExecuteReader();

    while (da.Read())
    {
        txtID.Text = da.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

The entries I have created so far in the `Student` table are as follows:

[image]

How can I ensure that the latest/desired `MyId` value is displayed in the ID text-box? Additionally, how do I make sure the user is not allowed to make further entries in the table after S99?

Comment: for the display part something like: `txtID.Text = da.GetValue(0) < 99 ? "Id too large" : "S" + da.GetValue(0).ToString("D2");` would work.

Comment: If you want to make sure the latest ID is displayed, then the user should not enter it, we humans make errors. You could use a SQL Server  `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE` and let the database give a new fresh Id to that student. Your Id assignment also has a flaw, when two users create students at the same time, you could potentially get  duplicated Id's.

Comment: @T.Schwarz also setting the [TextBox.MaxLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?view=netframework-4.7.2#system-windows-forms-textboxbase-maxlength) property would be wise.

Comment: @T.Schwarz Thank you for the response. What does `ToString("D2");` mean?

Comment: @Cleptus Thank you for the response. _You could use a SQL Server IDENTITY column or a SEQUENCE..._ When I used it, I realized that if I delete 2 items with Ids 1 and 2 from the database, the next item I create will have an Id of 3. In such a scenario, I want the new item to have an Id of 1. How can I ensure this happens with `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: D2 is the format shorthand for 2 decimal places or digits in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: @T.Schwarz Your comment was useful for me. You may post it as an answer if you wish.